# How to setup libusb with Qt on Mac Os X? (trying a cross-platform approach)

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qml, libusb

I'm triying to setup "libusb" on Qt 4.2.1 (Qt Creator 5.8) QML proyect. I really want to understand what to do after downloading the Lib, i have all the files but i don't know if i have to installed them on my system first or use them by just link them (btw, couldn't do it).

My .pro file goes like this:

```
QT += qml quick
QT += core gui

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += main.cpp

HEADERS  += libusb-1.0.21/libusb/libusb.h

INCLUDEPATH +=/usr/local/include/libusb-1.0
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lusb-1.0

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

QML_IMPORT_PATH =

QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

DISTFILES +=
```

It 'd be really helpful if someone could explained how is the process of installing, including libs.

My App targets Desktop and Cross-Platform (Linux, Windows, MacOs)

Answer (score 0):

You should check a package manager like [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install these kind of libraries. It the easiest way in my opinion. You could also consider installing `pkgconfig` via this tool. With both the qmake should have something like this if I'm not mistaken:

`CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += libusb-1.0`